# Template Function Parameter

Tags: c++, templates

**edit**: Solved. Was just a stupid order of definition mistake....

So I have a function that looks like this, in the header of a class called **Action**:

```
template <class Attacker, class Defender>
static int attack_result (Attacker A, Defender D) {
    //<snip>

    if (random(100) < res)
        return 1;

    //etc.
}
```

And I get this when compiling:

**error: there are no arguments to 'random' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'random' must be available
*note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)***

The function random() is declared in a static class called **Global** like this:

```
extern float random(int);
```

I'm calling Action::attack_result(...) from classes called **NPC** and **Player**, both of which are derived from a class called **Creature**. I don't think that's vital information, but I'll mention it in case it is. The parameters for Action::attack_result are both of Creature class.

I get why this error is being thrown, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried declaring Global in the Action header, I tried messing around with the keyword "using"...I can't go like this:

```
if (this->random(100) < res)
```

Because I get the following error (Creature, NPC, Player are static [and must be]):

**error: 'this' is unavailable for static member functions**

Going *Global::random(100)* does not work either:

**error: incomplete type 'Global' used in nested name specifier**

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: If `random` is a static member function of `Global`, then you should be able to call it with ```if(Global::random(100) < res)```. Did you mean to make `random` a static member function rather than an `extern` function?

Comment: If I use Global::random(100) I get this "error: incomplete type 'Global' used in nested name specifier". random is meant to be extern, yes.

Comment: @Matthew: Have you included the appropriate header?

Comment: @Matthew: Do not mutilate this question if you got a solution, rather accept the good solution.

Comment: @honk There was no correct solution, the problem was simply one of ordering a definition.

Comment: Why don't you post your definition of `Global`.

Comment: Do not mutilate this question if you do not have a problem anymore. Instead, you can answer to your own question with your fix and accept that. StackOverflow is not a chat; ideally your questions and its answers can help others in the future. 'Blanking' the question defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like random is in the Gloabl namespace so you need to call it like this `Global::random.`

Comment: error: incomplete type 'Global' used in nested name specifier

Comment: That means it can see a `class Global;` declaration but no `class Global { ... };` definition. Check your `#include` list.